# Android GCM example - how to implement in existing project?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, implementation

I've  downloaded the latest GCM example fromm Google on GitHub.

It works well, but I can't make it work in my own project.
I've got the donut turning and the message "Generating InstanceID token..."

I didn't understand the link with the class GcmSender in their example.

Here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

        private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
        private ProgressBar mRegistrationProgressBar;
        private TextView mInformationTextView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // url
            String url="http://www.monurl.org/";
            WebView mWview=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
            //autorise javascript
            mWview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWview.loadUrl(url);

            //partie notif

            mRegistrationProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.registrationProgressBar);
            mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    mRegistrationProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                            .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                    if (sentToken) {
                        mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.gcm_send_message));
                    } else {
                        mInformationTextView.setText(getString(R.string.token_error_message));
                    }
                }
            };
            mInformationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);


            // check si Google Play Services APK est sur le phone
            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyGcmRegistrationIntentService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }



        /**
         * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
         * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
         * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
         */
        private boolean checkPlayServices() {
            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                            PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Ce peripherique n'est pas supporte.");
                    finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

        private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
        public MyGcmListenerService() {
        }


        /**
         * Called when message is received.
         *
         * @param from SenderID of the sender.
         * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
         *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
         */
        // [START receive_message]
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
            String message = data.getString("message");
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

            /**
             * Production applications would usually process the message here.
             * Eg: - Syncing with server.
             *     - Store message in local database.
             *     - Update UI.
             */

            /**
             * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
             * that a message was received.
             */
            sendNotification(message);
        }
        // [END receive_message]



        /**
         * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
         *
         * @param message GCM message received.
         */
        private void sendNotification(String message) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

            Log.v("notification message",message);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class MyGcmRegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {


        private static final String TAG = "MyGcmRegistrationIntentService";
        private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};




        /**
         * Starts this service to perform action Foo with the given parameters. If
         * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
         *
         * @see IntentService
         */
        // TODO: Customize helper method
        public static void startActionFoo(Context context, String param1, String param2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyGcmRegistrationIntentService.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_FOO);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
            context.startService(intent);
        }

        /**
         * Starts this service to perform action Baz with the given parameters. If
         * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
         *
         * @see IntentService
         */
        // TODO: Customize helper method
        public static void startActionBaz(Context context, String param1, String param2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyGcmRegistrationIntentService.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_BAZ);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM1, param1);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM2, param2);
            context.startService(intent);
        }

        public MyGcmRegistrationIntentService() {
           // super("MyGcmRegistrationIntentService");
            // ajout
            super(TAG);
                    //fin ajout
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            try {
                // In the (unlikely) event that multiple refresh operations occur simultaneously,
                // ensure that they are processed sequentially.
                synchronized (TAG) {
                    // [START register_for_gcm]
                    // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
                    // are local.
                    // [START get_token]
                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                    String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    // [END get_token]
                    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

                    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
                    sendRegistrationToServer(token);

                    // Subscribe to topic channels
                    subscribeTopics(token);

                    // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
                    // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
                    // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
                    // [END register_for_gcm]
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
                // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
                // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
            }
            // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
            Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);


        }

        /**
         * Handle action Foo in the provided background thread with the provided
         * parameters.
         */
        private void handleActionFoo(String param1, String param2) {
            // TODO: Handle action Foo
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        /**
         * Handle action Baz in the provided background thread with the provided
         * parameters.
         */
        private void handleActionBaz(String param1, String param2) {
            // TODO: Handle action Baz
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }


        private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
            for (String topic : TOPICS) {
                GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
                pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
            }
        }


        /**
         * Persist registration to third-party servers.
         *
         * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
         * maintained by your application.
         *
         * @param token The new token.
         */
        private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
            // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        }

        private void sendTokenToServer(String token) {


        }


    }
```

```
    public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
    public MyInstanceIDListenerService() {
    }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

            // pour les notifs
        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
                // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyGcmRegistrationIntentService.class);
                startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide some source code of integrating the example into your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I found what happened, I've forgotten this in Main

```
       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
            super.onPause();
        }
```